# ElasticSearch aggregations using filter and without it

Tags: elasticsearch

I`m building product list page with filters. There a lot of filters, and data for them are counting in ES with aggregation functions.
Simplest example if min/max price:

```html
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "shop_id": 44
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "CategoryId": 36898
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "products_status": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "availability": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "min_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "products_price"
      }
    },
    "max_price": {
      "max": {
        "field": "products_price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, this request in ES return me minimal and maximal price according rules installed in filter (category_id 36898, shop_id 44 etc).
It is working perfect.

The question is: is it possible to update this request and get aggregations without filters? Or is it maybe possible to return aggregation data with another filter in one request?

So I want:

min_price and max_price for filtered data (query1)

and mix_price and max_price for unfiltered data (or filtered data with query 2)?

Comment: hey thank you for your question: your query return king of "without_filter_max" => array:2 [▼ "doc_count" => 20 "price_value" => array:1 [▼ "value" => 583.0 ] ] is it possible to make the result looks like this :"without_filter_max" => array:1 [▼ "value" => 583.0 ] ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use [global](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) option for the aggregations to not applying any filters provided in query block.

For example, for your query use the following json input.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "shop_id": 44
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "CategoryId": 36898
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "products_status": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "availability": 3
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
            "min": {
                "field": "products_price"
            }
        },
        "max_price": {
            "max": {
                "field": "products_price"
            }
        },
        "without_filter_min": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
                "price_value": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "products_price"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "without_filter_max": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
                "price_value": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "products_price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thank you for your response: your query return king of 
```"without_filter_max" => array:2 [▼
    "doc_count" => 20
    "price_value" => array:1 [▼
      "value" => 583.0
    ]
  ]```
is it possible to make the result looks like this :```"without_filter_max" => array:1 [▼
      "value" => 583.0
  ]``` ??

Comment: I think it's not possible, since `without_filter_max` is for fetching unfiltered data and then it will find max value through inner aggregation `price_value`